# Range facet with different gaps/steps in Solr

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

Currently the request is

```
{
  "query": "*:*",
  "facet": {
    "prices": {
      "type": "range",
      "field": "price",
      "start": 0,
      "end": 100,
      "gap": 20
    }
  }
}
```

I need to retrieve the counts for the ranges

```
0 TO 5
5 TO 10
10 TO 20
20 TO 30
30 TO 40
40 TO 50
50 TO 100
100 TO ?(NO END)
```

How to should be the request to retrieve the counts for these ranges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [range parameters listing shows you the available parameters](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/json-facet-api.html#range-facet-parameters) and their meaning. To get `5` as the gap, use `"gap": 5`. To get the entries that lie outside of your ranges, include `"other": "after"`:

```
  "type": "range",
  "field": "price",
  "start": 0,
  "end": 100,
  "gap": 5,
  "other": "after"
```

For your custom ranges, you'll need to [include the ranges explicitly](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/json-facet-api.html#arbitrary-range). You can't use `other` together with `range`, but there are ways around that:

```
  "ranges": [
      {"range": "[0, 5)"},
      {"range": "[5, 10)"},
      {"range": "[10, 20)"},
      {"range": "[20, 30)"},
      {"range": "[30, 40)"},
      {"range": "[40, 50)"},
      {"range": "[50, 100)"},
      {"range": "[100, *]"},
  ]
```